# CiviEvent not registering via backend

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration

Just updated to Civi 4.7.22, running WP 4.8, [edited] now running php7.0 [/edit] php 5.5.26

After the upgrade CiviEvent will no longer register contacts for events via the backend. After filling out the details and pressing the ok button, everything greys out - I get a 'processing' but nothing happens.

The green CiviCRM logo isn't turning, the page tab isn't updating, nothing. If I move away from the page I get a warning that things aren't saved (which is correct) but even after 5min it hasn't completed.

I'm about to roll back to CiviCRM4.7.17 which will throw a load of security complaints but at least folks will be able to register for events.

Any thoughts before I roll back?[image]
[added]With payment recording unchecked[image]

Comment: John - if unchecking the Record Payment resolves your issue then we have encountered the same issue and developed a fix. It will be contributed back to core and available in the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't solve the problem. Still switches to 'processing' but does nothing. I have taken a payment, with a successful booking, so that's working - just the admin route that's not functioning.

Comment: Could this be a PHP problem because PHP v 5.5x is deprecated and v5.6+ is recommended.  See CiviCRM PHP Requirements at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements

Comment: [edited] No, upgraded to php7.0 (CiviRM confirms this on sys check) -
 still not working. :( Thanks - will check upgrading my hosting to php 5.6+

Comment: Just tried moving away from the page, gives the warning that edits aren't saved - selecting 'Stay' starts the CiviCRM green triangle spinning, but doesn't refresh the page with the saved event registration. Even after a couple of minutes.

Comment: On a hunch, just tried disabling & uninstalling CiviDiscount - that didn't make any difference. Looks like a roll back is on the cards. :(

Comment: Can you try granting permissions to "access CiviCRM” and "access CiviEvent” for anonymous users and see if that helps? This is just a hunch, but I've seen other CiviEvent issues in 4.7.20/21/22 that were "fixed" using this method. While it's not a permanent solution, it might be helpful to know if there's a correlation.

Comment: I'm logged in as admin so that shouldn't be the issue? And giving that level of access to anonymous users would by-pass any security and allow anyone to add events? That doesn't sound like a viable 'solution'. I've actually now rolled back to 4.7.17 - the security warnings are back but I can add event participants. I'll try updated one version at a time and see if / where the problem replicates.

Comment: Updated to 4.7.23 and it allows civievent updated via backend again - might have been a <.22 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was resolved in the latest 4.7.23 release.